# Why am I having a "%" sign between the lines in integrated terminal in VS Code?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, visual-studio-code

I was trying to setup zsh shell with oh-my-zsh in vs code. But in the left prompt why there is a "%" sign between lines? How to remove the "%" marked in the screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to issue the following:

```
unsetopt PROMPT_SP
```

This option is explained in `man zshoptions` as follows (highlighting is mine):

> Attempt to preserve a partial line (i.e. a line that did not end with
>   a newline)  that  would  otherwise  be covered  up by the command
>   prompt due to the PROMPT_CR option.  This works by outputting some
>   cursor-control characters, including a series of spaces, that should
>   make the terminal wrap to the next line when a partial line  is 
>   present  (note that this is only successful if your terminal has
>   automatic margins, which is typi‐ cal).
>
> When a partial line is preserved, **by default you will see an
>   inverse+bold character at the end of  the  partial  line:   a `%`
>   for a normal user** or a `#` for root.  If set, the shell parameter
>   PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used to customize how the end of partial lines
>   are shown.
>
> NOTE: if the PROMPT_CR option is not set, enabling this option will
>   have no effect.  This option  is  on  by default.

Answer (score 0):

The [Agnoster theme](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme) which you're using requires a patched font that contains some special symbols to display properly. Excerpt from its README:

> NOTE: In all likelihood, you will need to install a [Powerline-patched font](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts) for this theme to render correctly.

Switch to a font with Powerline support to solve this. I'm using [Hack](https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/), it's Powerline-compatible out of the box, no patching required.

Font can be changed in VS Code settings.